# Differentiation of product of one parameter subgroups

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $G$ be a Lie group. Let $\gamma,\rho : I \to G$ be two smooth curves such that $\gamma(0) = \rho(0) = I$ the identity and $\gamma'(0) =A$ and $\gamma'(0) = B$ for some $A,B \in G$.

> > **My question is:** Is there a "product rule" for calculating
> >     $$ \frac{d}{dt} \gamma(t)\rho(t) \Bigg|_{t=0}?$$

I am guessing that the answer should be $\gamma'(0)\rho(0) + \gamma(0)\rho'(0)$ but then I run into trouble:

1. $\gamma'(0)$ is an element of the Lie algebra while $\rho(0)$ is an element of the Lie group
2. What does it make sense to "add"?

Can this "product rule" be interpreted in a correct sense?

I have searched through my copy of Lee's *Smooth Manifolds* but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the group operation on $G$ by $m$, then you want to find the right formula for $\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}m(\gamma(t),\rho(t))$. By the chain-rule we can write this as $\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}m(\gamma(t),\rho(0)) + \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}m(\gamma(0),\rho(t)) = \gamma^\prime(0)+\rho^\prime(0)$.

This addition is defined since $\gamma^\prime(0)$ and $\rho^\prime(0)$ are elements of the Lie Algebra.
In fact, this essentially defines addition on the Lie Algebra.